# Page content is falling below div

Tags: html, css

I've been updating our website to include some more detailed product search categories. Everything is in a main "content" div but these new lists are extending past the content div and are just being placed over the whole site background. You can see the page here: http://promo-central.com/products/

I'd like to have the white background from content extend all the way to the blue footer like my other pages.

Any ideas as to why this is occurring? I am self taught writing code, so I am learning as I go.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to `#content` CSS

Should be:

```
#content {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  color: #111111;
  font-size: medium;
  min-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That does it. Can yo tell me why you recommend also adding the none repeat scroll 0 0 to background? Thanks!

Comment: I just copied whole code from Firebug, it added this automatically. ;) These are "final styles" after browser interpretation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The height of the "productcategories" div is 0. Set it to a real height and it will extend the white container.